# oracle is gather statistics globally when granularity level is partition

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have the following function to gather statistics.

```
FUNCTION generate_stats(tabelname IN VARCHAR2
                       ) RETURN NUMBER
IS 
    current_user                VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv','current_schema') INTO current_user FROM DUAL;
    BEGIN
        dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => current_user, tabname => tabelname, granularity=>'PARTITION', cascade => true) ;
    END;
    RETURN 0;
END generate_stats;
```

However, I noticed that it generates table statistics when it is called
[image]

I don't understand why it is generating statistics for the table also.

Comment: The SELECT statement and the variable `current_user` are redundant to use, you can just remove them and replace `ownname => current_user` with `ownname => SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','current_schema')`

Comment: you tagged this as Oracle 10g, is that really the version?